# conditional types parameters in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm attempting to create a function where the `columns` parameter depends on what `type` has been selected.

`function useNavigation(type: "horizontal" | "grid" | "vertical", columns?: number)`

How to change that type declaration to set that columns parameter is `required` when parameter `type` is `grid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function overloads to achieve this. In my example below, the first two declarations are specifying different arguments based on your requirements whereas the last declaration (and consequently the implementation) receives all possible arguments, which is why `type` is still `'horizontal' | 'vertical' | 'grid'`.

The caller will get proper types and auto-completion, you'll simply have to do the checks inside the function to determine your logic based on the arguments.

```js
function useNavigation(type: 'horizontal' | 'vertical');
function useNavigation(type: 'grid', columns: number);
function useNavigation(
  type: 'horizontal' | 'vertical' | 'grid',
  columns?: number,
) {
  // Your function body...
}
```

Here's a TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABCAzgUwHIEMBuMDmWsCAFFAJ4AOaAXIgOQAWcATjAF4JRYA29iAHwY40LWBF70AlHXABrMHADuYANwAoUJGJJUmXASLwwZKrQb42AE3oAaRBDg8QAWzAo6YVwCNRM5GAKymqa4NDGyOjYeIQ6JOqIiBTUdEysHFySgsKi4llC9JYwNrYJDk6u7gD8nj6ipf7yiiqIAN5lAPQdiACacCAsiFrhcG6I3nBW5AB0s+oAvurqXYgAarzF6nrRhnFpbJxg3HxSGtsGscYk9CJiMBInZ1EXRqSF1naIAEynSysAkmAcBsrFtnjFXiZ9hkjpJ7D8nvoIXtbnk+PDfudkVd3sVpBolokgA) demonstrating this.

Comment: @piotr.schaar OP this is a more efficient answer.

Comment: To be fair, @catchergeese's answer is just as valid (even provides better type checking **inside** the function but requires a different signature.

Comment: yea I don't think his answer is wrong. Just that function overloading is more readable at first glance plus you'd still have to destructure `options` within his function.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally (pre TS 2.8 or TS 3.0) you could only use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to achieve this, but now I'd be inclined to use a [tuple-typed rest parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types); specifically a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of such tuple types:

```
function useNavigation(...args:
    [type: "horizontal" | "vertical", columns?: number] |
    [type: "grid", columns: number]
) { }
```

That means the arguments to `useNavigation()` must either be: a pair where the first element is `"horizontal"` or `"vertical"` and the second element is an optional `number` value; *or* a pair where the first element is `"grid"` and the second element is a *required* `number` value.

You can test that it works as desired:

```
useNavigation("horizontal") // okay
useNavigation("vertical", 20); // okay
useNavigation("grid", 10); //okay
useNavigation("grid"); // error!
// ---------> ~~~~~~
// Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
```

---

Note that the type signature for `useNavigation()` is also taking advantage of [labeled tuple elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#labeled-tuple-elements), to show that we intend the caller to think of the first argument as having a name of `type` and the second argument as having a name of `columns`.  Such labels are only relevant when it comes to type hints in IntelliSense and do not affect the types or runtime behavior.  In particular, there is no variable named `type` or `columns` here; the function implementation sees only an `args` array:

```
function useNavigation(...args:
    [type: "horizontal" | "vertical", columns?: number] |
    [type: "grid", columns: number]
) {    
    if (args[0] === "grid") {
        args[1].toFixed(); // okay
    } 
}
```

You could, if you want, destructure `args` into `type` and `columns` variables as in

```
const [type, columns] = args;
```

but there is an advantage to leaving it as `args`; namely, that the compiler sees `args` as a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type.  Note that in the above implementation, the compiler sees that if `args[0] === "grid"`, then `args[1]` is definitely a `number` and not possibly `undefined`.  Compare to the behavior when you separate `args` out into two no-longer-seen-as-correlated variables:

```
if (type === "grid") {
    columns.toFixed(); // oops, possibly undefined
}
```

The compiler only sees `columns` as type `number | undefined` regardless of whether or not you check `type === "grid"` first.  This might not be a big deal to you, but discriminated unions are useful enough that I wanted to point it out.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#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)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite pattern to achieve some additional parameters to be required for some parameter(s) is to wrap it in an object and type it as:

```
function useNavigation(options: { type: "horizontal" | "vertical"; columns?: number } | { type: "grid", columns: number })
```

and use it as

```
useNavigation({ type: "horizontal" })
useNavigation({ type: "grid", columns: 12 })
```

It may feel a little bit repetitive but provides good typesafely, also when types are narrowed down after property check

```
if (options.type === "grid") {
 // here typescript knows that `columns` exists
}
```